# Swift 4 UITableView make one cell as UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a dynamic `Table` as `UITableView` and all cells are as normal (retrieved form my `array`)
However I need only one cell as TextView to be able input text. On text Change I need to retrieve the text user input.
How to make this?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count+1 //to allow this input field
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(indexPath.row < array.cont){
       //normal cell from array
        let cell =  Table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        cell?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
        cell?.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center;
        return cell!;
    }else{
      //create input text field (DON'T KNOW HOW)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if(indexPath.row < array.cont){
              //.. perform action ..
       }else{
         //retrieve input text (DONT know How)
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating `UITextView` inside `UITableViewCell` is quite simple :

```
let textView: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 311.00, height: 50.00))  // Set frames as per requirements
textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
cell.contentView.addSubView(textView)
```

But this would lead to incorrect values while scrolling the table. Best approach would be to create a custom cell and add `UITextView` there. Here is the custom cell. Keep the constraints intact.

[image]

Before using the custom cell, you need to register it in your table. So :

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "TextCell", bundle: nil)
Table.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextCell")
```

Don't forget to put identifier of cell in xib.

[image]

Now in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(indexPath.row < array.cont){
       //normal cell from array
        let cell =  Table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        cell?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
        cell?.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center;
        return cell!;
    }else{
      //create input text field (DON'T KNOW HOW)
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextCell", for: indexPath) as! TextCell
      // Access UITextView by cell.textView
      return cell
    }
}
```

The main issue is - dynamic cell size as per `UITextView` height. But that entirely depends on your requirement. You can follow [**this**](http://candycode.io/self-sizing-uitextview-in-a-uitableview-using-auto-layout-like-reminders-app/) post for that.

Comment: This is not the best approach because this cell could get reused and you will have text views on incorrect cells or multiple text views on cells. It's is much better to create a custom cell with a text view built into it and dequeue that kind of custom cell for the appropriate index path.

Comment: @maddy : Good point. But I am keeping that away from the scope since OP knows about that (he's already working on cell subviews). But I understand your concern. Will update my answer.

Comment: No, the OP not working on cell subviews. So far only a standard `UITableViewCell`. Your answer is just going to lead to more problems and questions.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with delegation pattern or NSNotification.
Here's the solution for this using delegation pattern.

1. Create new UITableViewCell using xib and add the textView on contentView of cell, set the reuse identifier and than register the xib in the ViewController with

   tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "name of the xib file", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Identifier here")
2. Now define protocol anywhere outside of the class
   // You can give any name 
   // Here we are confirming to class to avoid any retain cycles

   protocol CustomCellDelegate :class {
   func returnText(text :String)
   }
3. Now initialise " var delegate : CustomCellDelegate? " in same class of UITableViewCell that we created above while creating xib.
   and confirm to protocol UITextViewDelegate and than in the cell class write this

   override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   textView.delegate = self
   }

after that add these functions in same class of tableViewCell

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if(text == "\n") {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        delegate.returnText(text : textView.text ?? "")
}
```

4. Now in the ViewController class

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
               if indexPath.row == array.count { // this will call the cell with TextView at the end , you can play with any indexPath to call the cell

                let cell = tableView.de... // Deque the cell with TextView here using reuse identifier
                cell.delegate = self
                return cell
               }
              else {
                // deque other cells
             }
   }
   ```

we'll write an extension of ViewController and confirm to our custom protocol

```
extension ViewController : CustomCellDelegate {

// this function will get called when you end editing on textView
 func returnText(text :String) {
  print(text) // you may save this string in any variable in ViewController class 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a TextView in to your custom cell, hide it, show when you need

Comment: Why hide it and show it? Use two different types of cell. That's the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have the textView on the top of all cells, drag and drop a UIView inside the tableView before the cell.

[image]

this view will scroll with cells.

design this view as you need insert a textView inside it, and use textView's delegate methods to perform operations.